# Java Generic Matrix creation

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, arraylist

I want to create a generic type matrix in java with the dimension size will be randomised.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Generate a random positive integer, & allocate array of that size.  Or have you not explained your problem completely?

Comment: What is "dimension size"?  Do you mean "size", or "number of dimensions" .... or both.  And what do mean by generic matrix?   A general matrix ... or a matrix whose element type is a Java generic type identifier?

Answer (score 1):

Creating matrices in Java is not as friendly as say R, or Matlab, or even C.  The very strong Typing paradigm of Java means that everything has to be defined or initialized.  So you cant simply do Integers[x][y][z].  Beyond an array of arrays, things get hairy.

The difference is in a regular matrix moving in +x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z are all essentially equivalent.  However in Java, if you want to think of three dimensions of a matrix, they are directional.  Meaning you have to traverse X, then traverse Y, then traverse Z, always in that order.  And to move say x+1, you have to go back down z, back down y, and then move your x position, then turn around and traverse y again and z again. 
I am not sure that made sense. but that is how I have to think about matrices in Java or else I start making coding errors.

There are libraries for java that focus on creating a matrix.  You could look there.  http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Just creating a random array of arrays (a psuedomatrix as described above) doesn't seem hard overall.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Rand
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Random random = new Random();
     int dim1 = random.nextInt( 10 );
      int dim2 = random.nextInt( 10 );
      int dim3 = random.nextInt( 10 );

      int[][][] matrix = new int[dim1][dim2][];

      //use dim 3 when you do the specific the declaration for the 3rd dimension

   }

}
```

Running quickly through some examples- 
      Int myIntArray = new int[15]; 
Creates a 15 member int array, initialized to the Default value for that type, which is 0 for 
      //--Assigning values
      myIntArray[2] = 5; 
      //=  0 0 5 0 0
      myInt = myIntArray[2];
      myInt = 5;

```
// @Initializing with values

   int[5] myIntArray = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
   int[] myIntArray = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 };
```

Multidimensional array are not like a matrix in C. All dimensions are the same type.Each element is an independent array. Each array element of an earlier dimension is an array.All dimensions are of the same type and each element is an independent array.
In Java, each array element of a multidimensional array except the
last dimension is an array, not an individual element
       //    Two dim array

```
  int[][] myIntArray2;
  //Or
  int myIntArray[][];
```

Use the new operator to allocate.Allocation initializes to the DEFault
type.In this case you are initializing an array of arrays, so the DEFault
type is null.

```
  int[][] myIntArray2d = new int[5][];
  myIntArray2d[3] = new int[5];
```

So assigning the array above, you get

```
  null Null 0 Null Null
  []    []  0 []   [] 
  []    []  0 []   [] 
  []    []  0 []   [] 
  []    []  0 []   []
```

The empty, Defaults in the 1st dim are null - the Default array type.The second dimension has to be initialized before accessing.

```
  char[][] charArray = new char[36][];

  //But I cant save anything into  

 charArray[4][0]; 

  //because it has not been initialized with a separate new statement.
  //This is why you leave the 3rd dim off until later.

 char[5]  = new char[5]; // WRONG
  char[] f = new char[5];
  //Now I can follow that with
  charArray[5][5] = 'a';  
  //or from about
  intArray[5][5][5]= 3;
  // But you cant declare the final dimension until later.

  int[3][] arr =  ( { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { 5, 10, 15, 20 });
  //is an array[2] with 3 arrays
  int[][] arr =   { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { 5, 10, 15, 20 }; 
  //is an array[2] with 3 arrays
```

This is why you cant really do matrixes in Java.  Because each final dimension can technically vary.

When copying an array into a variable - i.e.

```
  charArrayvars = charArray[5]
  int[] Copies= { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  } //as a pointer not the data.

  // This means that
  int[3] ArrayA = { 1, 2, 3 };
  Int[3] ArrayB = { 4, 5, 6 };
  ArrayB = Array A;

  //So ArrayB now references Array A.
   //Now if I set

  ArrayA[0] = 0; //then
   if( ArrayB[0] = 0 &&  ArrayA==ArrayB.){}
  //  The logic comparator really just shows they use the same reference.
```

I  think though I would evaluate your objectives and see if there is another way.  Or maybe use a library.  Because a matrix like you are thinking is not native to Java.  There are lots of strange behaviors which I have done a terrible job explaining.